# How do i go to a specific cPanel page with an auto-login script (PHP)

Tags: php, cpanel, whm, autologin

I have a PHP script which auto-logins a user into cPanel, all works great! However, Instead of landing on the homepage of cPanel, I would like to go to a page on cPanel such as email accounts.

Here is the working code:

```html
<?php

// This can also be the reseller who owns the cPanel user.
$whmusername = "****";
$whmpassword = "****";


// The user on whose behalf the API call runs.
$cpanel_user = "****"; //under reseller

$end_parameter = "/frontend/paper_lantern/email_accounts/index.html#/list";

$servername = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];


$query = "https://" . $servername . ":2087/json-api/create_user_session?api.version=1&user=$cpanel_user&service=cpaneld";

$curl = curl_init();                                     // Create Curl Object.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);       // Allow self-signed certificates...
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);       // and certificates that don't match the hostname.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);               // Do not include header in output
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);        // Return contents of transfer on curl_exec.
$header[0] = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($whmusername.":".$whmpassword) . "\n\r";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);         // Set the username and password.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $query);                 // Execute the query.
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if ($result == false) {
    error_log("curl_exec threw error \"" . curl_error($curl) . "\" for $query");
                                                    // log error if curl exec fails
}


$decoded_response = json_decode( $result, true );
$targetURL = $decoded_response['data']['url'];


header("Location: " . $targetURL);
die();

?>
```

As you can see from the code, it creates a session with my WHM credentials ($whmusername/$whmpassword) and auto-logins to cPanel with a specific user ($cpanel_user).

After a successful login, it will redirect to the cPanel homepage using a header ($targetURL). I'm trying to add a parameter to go to a specific page ($end_parameter) but unfortunately I'm not having much luck.

The url to the email page is: /frontend/paper_lantern/email_accounts/index.html#/list

I'm not sure how to implement that url into the $targetURL.

What i have tried:

```
$targetURL = $decoded_response['data']['url'] . $end_parameter;
```

The full url to the email account page is: https://myserver:2083/cpsess8368800249/frontend/paper_lantern/email_accounts/index.html#/list

Any ideas?

Comment: hai. it's the quistion i have searching now, i hope you got the right answer, so can you provide the code for us ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the LogMeIn:

```
class LogMeIn {
// The available services with their HTTPS ports
private static $servicePorts = array('cpanel' => 2083, 'whm' => 2087, 'webmail' => 2096);
public static function getLoggedInUrl($user, $pass, $hostname, $service, $goto = '/') {
    // If no valid service has been given, default to cPanel
    $port = isset(self::$servicePorts[$service]) ? self::$servicePorts[$service] : 2083;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $fields = array('user' => $user, 'pass' => $pass, 'goto_uri' => $goto);
    // Sets the POST URL to something like: https://example.com:2083/login/
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://' . $hostname . ':' . $port . '/login/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    // Turn our array of fields into a url encoded query string i.e.: ?user=foo&pass=bar
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
    // RFC 2616 14.10 compliance
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection' => 'close'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Execute POST query returning both the response headers and content into $page
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $session = $token = array();
    // Find the session cookie in the page headers
    if(!preg_match('/session=([^\;]+)/', $page, $session)) {
        // This will also fail if the login authentication failed. No need to explicitly check for it.
        return false;
    }
    // Find the cPanel session token in the page content
    if(!preg_match('|<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh"[^>]+URL=/(cpsess\d+)/|i', $page, $token)) {
        return false;
    }
    // Append the goto_uri to the query string if it's been manually set
    $extra = $goto == '/' ? '' : '&goto_uri=' . urlencode($goto);
    return 'https://' . $hostname . ':' . $port . '/' . $token[1] . '/login/?session=' . $session[1] . $extra;
    }
}
```

URL GitHub: https://gist.github.com/kmark/4440574

Fórum cPanel with response: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/php-code-to-login-to-webmail.387592/